# PostgreSQL error logging options not recognised

Tags: postgresql, copy, postgresql-9.3

As noted [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Error_logging_in_COPY) I'm trying to use the PostgreSQL COPY ERROR_LOGGING, ERROR_LOGGING_SKIP_BAD_ROWS options.

My SQL looks like this:

```
COPY users FROM 'C:\Users\admin\osmosis_temp\users.txt'
    (ERROR_LOGGING, ERROR_LOGGING_SKIP_BAD_ROWS);
```

I get an SQL output of `ERROR:  option "error_logging" not recognized`. Am I missing something that turns on the error logging in the first place?

PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the wiki page you've linked to one reads:

> Error logging in COPY was a proposed feature developed by Aster Data against the PostgreSQL 9.0 code base. It was submitted and reviewed (1) but **not accepted into the core product for that or any other version so far**.

So that was only a concept.

Comment: ok great, id there a way to try/except SQL errors using COPY?